# setuid() before calling execv() in vfork() / clone()

Tags: c, linux

I need to fork an exec from a server. Since my servers memory foot print is large, I intend to use `vfork()` / linux `clone()`. I also need to open pipes for `stdin` / `stdout` / `stderr`. Is this allowed with `clone()` / `vfork()`?

Comment: Why use `vfork()` at all? `fork()` doesn't actually copy the memory of your process -- the pages are mapped into both processes with copy-on-write semantics. See the BUGS section of the man page for `vfork()`.

Comment: @FatalError the memory manager still needs to reserve the pages, which requires overcommit.

Comment: `fork` momentarily doubles the commit charge, and thus fails if there's not enough memory for 2 copies of the process. `vfork` solves this problem. The fact that new physical memory will never be instantiated for 99% of the writable pages in the child is irrelevant; the kernel cannot know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard:

> [..] the behaviour is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec` family of functions.

The problem with calling functions like `setuid` or `pipe` is that they could affect memory in the address space shared between the parent and child processes.  If you need to do anything before `exec`, the best way is to write a small shim process that does whatever you need it to and then `exec`s to the eventual child process (perhaps arguments supplied through `argv`).

```
shim.c
======

enum {
    /* initial arguments */
    ARGV_FILE = 5, ARGV_ARGS
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* consume instructions from argv */
    /* setuid, pipe() etc. */
    return execvp(argv[ARGV_FILE], argv + ARGV_ARGS);
}
```

Comment: This is my chosen solution since it is portable across *nix flavours.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `clone()` instead, using `CLONE_VFORK|CLONE_VM` flags; see [man 2 clone](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html) for details.

Because `CLONE_FILES` is not set, the child process has its own file descriptors, and can close and open standard descriptors without affecting the parent at all.

Because the cloned process is a separate process, it has its own user and group ids, so setting them via `setresgid()` and `setresuid()` (perhaps calling `setgroups()` or `initgroups()` first to set the additional groups -- see [man 2 setresuid](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setresgid.2.html), [man 2 setgroups](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setgroups.2.html), and [man 3 initgroups](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/initgroups.3.html) for details) will not affect the parent at all.

The `CLONE_VFORK|CLONE_VM` flags mean this `clone()` should behave like `vfork()`, with the child process running in the same memory space as the parent process up till the `execve()` call.

This approach avoids the latency when using an intermediate executable -- it is pretty significant --, but the approach completely Linux-specific.

Comment: Isn't this what vfork() on linux maps to?